# How can I delete the specific list element I clicked on the Delete submit in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm developing a project with EJS for the first time. In the project, I get an incorrect result:

[image]

What I want is to be able to select the list elements one by one and delete them with delete. Additionally, I'm wondering if it's the right approach to use so many forms in the ejs file.

**My codes are as follows:**

**list.ejs**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="date">
        <span><%= new Date().getDate() %> <%= locals.thismonth %> <%= locals.thisyear %>, <%= locals.thisday %></span>
    </div>
       
<div class="tasks">
    <% if (locals.task) { %>
            <% locals.tasklist.forEach(element => { %> 
                <form action="/delete" method="POST">
                    <div class="task">
                        <div class="description">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                                <p><%= element %></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button">
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="deleteButton">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <% locals.i =  locals.i+1; %>
            <% }); %>            
    <% } else { %>
            <div class="task">
                <span>Add task</span>
            </div>
    <% } %>
        <form action="/delete-all" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete All" class="deleteAllButton">
        </form>
</div>

<form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <div class="add">
            <input type="submit" value="+" class="addButton">
            <input type="text" name="addtask" id="create" placeholder="Create a new task" class="create">
        </div>   
</form>

</div>
```

**index.js**

```
import express, { request } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { localsName } from "ejs";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

const d = new Date();
let month = months[d.getMonth()];
let day = days[ d.getDay() === 0 ? d.getDay()+6 : d.getDay()-1];
let year = d.getFullYear();

let taskList = [];
let newTaskList = [];
let index = 0;
let newItem ="";
let text = "";

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => { 
    index = 0;
    taskList = [];
    res.render("app.ejs", {thisday: day, thismonth: month, thisyear: year});
})

app.post("/delete", (req, res) => { 
    console.log(text);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(taskList); 
    let taskIndex = taskList.indexOf(text);  
    taskList = taskList.splice(taskIndex,1);
    console.log(taskIndex);
    res.render("app.ejs", {ntasklist: newTaskList, tasklist: taskList, i: index, task: text, thisday: day, thismonth: month, thisyear: year});
})

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
    text = req.body["addtask"];
    if (text !== "" ) {
        // taskList[index] = text;
        taskList.push(text);
        // console.log(text);
    }
    // index++;
    res.render("app.ejs", {ntasklist: newTaskList, tasklist: taskList, i: index, task: text, thisday: day, thismonth: month, thisyear: year});
})

app.post("/delete-all", (req, res) => { 
    taskList = [];
    res.render("app.ejs", {ntasklist:newTaskList, tasklist: taskList, i: index, task: text, thisday: day, thismonth: month, thisyear: year});
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Surver running on port ${port}.`);
})
```

**The result in the terminal is as follows:**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Surver running on port 3000.
c
0
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
2
```

I want is to be able to select the list elements one by one and delete them with delete.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="what you want to pass">` and `text = req.body["checkbox"];`

Comment: I also try this but it didn't work.